# Optimization bizarre local minimum

Tags: optimization, nonlinear-optimization

I have a cost function that I can calculate the gradient of. I am minimizing the cost function with respect to a vector of variables. However, no matter how large the actual solution, local minimum where i get stuck is always the same
i.e. let us say the solution is $[50,50,50]^T$, local minimum gets stuck at [-5,-5,-5]. Let us say the solution is $[60,60,60]^T$, local minimum again gets stuck at [-5,-5,-5]. If the actual solution is under a certain value, i.e. $[60,60,60]^T$, solution converges. I understand getting stuck at a minimum. But how come at the same local minimum for different actual solutions?

Cost function is as follows:
$ cost=\sum_{n}[(\alpha_n- \sum_{m}\beta_m \sum_{l}exp(-i\sum_{k}C_{lk}z_l)(\alpha_n- \sum_{m}\beta_m \sum_{l}exp(-i\sum_{k}C_{lk}z_l)^*]$
Taking its derivative w.r.t $z$ yields
$$(\nabla_z cost)_p= 2Re\sum_{n}[(\sum_{m}\beta_m \sum_{l}exp(-i\sum_{k}C_{lk}z_l)C_{lp}i)(\alpha_n- \sum_{m}\beta_m \sum_{l}exp(-i\sum_{k}C_{lk}z_l)^*]$$

Comment: Are you asking why the local minimum is always at the same spot, or are you asking why the numerics keep finding the local minimum instead of the global one? In any case, it would be helpful if you gave more details about the function.

Comment: I am asking why the local minimum is always at the same even if the global minimum changes

Comment: @strahd cause it depends on your function. Different functions with different global minimums can have identical local optimums. Also, it depends on the optimization algorithm your using, some are more prone to converge to local minima. It will probably help if you post the actual function / minimization problem

Comment: I edited my question adding the cost function. I understand your point, however, I am changing my function. That is why the global minimum moves. Lut local minimum stays the same.

Comment: your function has periods based on $C_{lk}$, if you don't change them, you might have local minima that don't change position, similar to $A\cos(\omega x)$ which will have minima at the same spots, independent of $A$. Have you verified numerically that $ [-5,-5,-5]$ is indeed a local minimum and that the gradient of the cost is indeed zero there?

Comment: I justed checked the solution that the solver converged and it is not a local optimum. I am using a backtracking line search. Could that be the reason that I cannot any other optimal points?